# Getting strange error with connect by clause in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a 2 test oracle databases and each of them contain a table called department (dept_no,dept_name, main_dept_no) where each department entry is connected to main department by dept_no in the MAIN_DEPT_NO column. 
The strange problem is when I execute the query on the 1 st database I get D.DEPT_NO is not available column (D.* all columns from department table) but it is there and what is more strange this query works fine on 2 nd database.

Is there any settings I have to do in the database so that it can work with connect by clause ?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LPAD(' ', 4*(LEVEL))  || '· ' ||DEPT_NAME,1,50)  DEPT_NAME_HY, D.*
FROM PERSONEL.DEPARTMENT D
START WITH MAIN_DEPT_NO IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR DEPT_NO=MAIN_DEPT_NO
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I did as follows,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LPAD(' ', 4*(LEVEL))  || '· ' ||DEPT_NAME,1,50)  DEPT_NAME_HY, D.DEPT_NO,D.DEPT_NAME,D.MAIN_DEPT_NO  
FROM PERSONEL.DEPARTMENT D
START WITH MAIN_DEPT_NO IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR DEPT_NO=MAIN_DEPT_NO
```

The query started working maybe in the oracle 11g D.* to work with connect by shout be in this way.

Comment: The code below fixes the issue. There seems to be a bug in the 11.2.0.1 release, workaround was: alter session set optimizer_features_enable='11.1.0.7'; (from Oracle support)

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixes the issue. 
There seems to be a bug in the 11.2.0.1 release, workaround was: 
alter session set optimizer_features_enable='11.1.0.7'; (from Oracle support)